# 64 bit smpp library for .net

Tags: .net, 64-bit, smpp

I'm currently using the devshock smpp library. unfortunatly it only appears to be available in 32 bit binaries. Does anyone know if they do a 64 bit version or if there is anywhere that does a decent 64-bit smpp library??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [RoaminSMPP](http://roaminsmpp.sourceforge.net/)? It is open source and is released as LGPL. It should work on x64 too.

Answer (score 1):

Zeocrash, I'm using Jaama SMPP Client for a while, and it's working neatly. Since it's developed in C#, I think you can [optimize it to 64bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203085/c-sharp-for-64bit-os), and [migrate it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx) easily.

Answer (score 0):

This commercial library:

http://www.tops.com.pl/en/products/smscc/

is 64 bit library. A decent one according to my experience. Requires at least .NET 2.0 to be present (there are rather no Windows machines today that would not have it already) but you can interface to it either as to a .NET component or through COM interface (like ActiveX in old days) so it can be used e.g. with 64 bit C++, not only CLR languages.